# How to delete Java Loggers

Tags: java, logging, memory-leaks

I have a memory leak in an application which creates many **java.util.logging.Logger** objects and I was able to boil the problem down to this:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LoggerTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new LoggerTest().createManyLoggers();
    }

    public void createManyLoggers() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(generateMemoryStatus("before"));

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(LoggerTest.class.getName() + "." + i);
        }

        System.out.println(generateMemoryStatus("after"));

        Thread.sleep(10000L);

        System.out.println(generateMemoryStatus("after cool off"));
    }

    private String generateMemoryStatus(String label)
    {
        System.gc();

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        long total = runtime.totalMemory();
        long free = runtime.freeMemory();
        long used = total - free;

        return String.format("used memory: %,10d bytes  %s", used, label);
    }
}
```

The javadoc of **java.util.logging.Logger** states:
*It is important to note that the Logger returned by one of the getLogger factory methods may be garbage collected at any time if a strong reference to the Logger is not kept.*

But the Loggers are not garbage collected and cause a memory leak - the output of the above code typically looks like this:

```
# java -version

java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

# java -jar loggerTest.jar

    used memory:  1.662.336 bytes  before
    used memory: 25.482.576 bytes  after
    used memory: 25.482.744 bytes  after cool off
```

I.e. it eats over 20MB of memory (also tried it inside eclipse). 
In the actual application, the parent loggers and all handlers are removed from the loggers, but since that does not make any difference, I omitted that here.

Calling

```
LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
```

does not help. So I'm going to create a pool of loggers for my application and reuse the loggers.

My question is this: Is there a way to actually delete **java.util.logging.Logger** objects i.e. remove them from memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot force the JVM to remove objects from memory.

The call to `System.gc()` do not guarantee that the garbage collector is run. If the JVM consider it has enough memory left, the call to `System.gc()` may simply be ignored.

Can you elaborate about your memory leak? I mean on a modern hardware and using a JVM, having 25Mb consumed by some objects is not what i would call a memory leak.

Have you concrete memory issues when running your application, like `OutOfMemoryError`?

You don't necessarily need to pool your objects, the JVM will remove them from memory when needed. If you just want to see that in action, just run with a smaller heap (e.g. `-Xmx15m`). But this is not a good idea. You shouldn't consider tweaking the memory unless you have issues, like `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll test it with a smaller heap.

Comment: Reducing the heap size did show, that the loggers are in fact garbage collected.

I set the heap size to 20MB and created double the number of loggers and the used memory always stayed below 14MB.